Predicción a partir de modelo de PCoA previo
he generado un modelo PCoA a partir de unos datos, mediante el siguiente código en R:
m_pcoa <- vegan::vegdist(df1, method = "euclidean", binary = FALSE)
m_pcoa <- ape::pcoa(m_pcoa)

Donde df1 es un dataframe con las lecturas de la secuenciación de muchas muestras de heces
Ahora tengo nuevos datos y quiero predecir los valores de las 2 primeras componentes de estos nuevos datos a partir del modelo anterior. He intentado utilizar predict() junto con el objeto m_pcoa, pero parece que no es la forma adecuada o no lo hago bien.
Si pudieseis indicarme cómo hacerlo de forma correcta, sería de gran ayuda.
Gracias.
Editado: 29/07/2024
Pongo ejemplo:
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"),
                           var2 = c(601, 584, 333, 245, 432),
                           var3 = c(5274, 1629, 5751, 6411, 7897),
                           var4 = c(73083, 22310, 85142, 11421, 61617))

rownames(df1) <- df1[ , 1]
df1 <- df1[ , -1]

pcoa1 <- vegan::vegdist(df1, method = "euclidean", binary = FALSE)
pcoa1 <- ape::pcoa(pcoa1)

df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c("p6", "p7", "p8"),
                           var2 = c(261, 435, 348),
                           var3 = c(2437, 5022, 9866),
                           var4 = c(31603, 17390, 40589))

rownames(df2) <- df2[ , 1]
df2 <- df2[ , -1]

pcoa2 <- predict(pcoa1, df2)

Y aquí me sale el siguiente error:
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "pcoa"


En la función predict, a parte del objeto tienes que incluirle los datos para los que quieres calcular el valor; es decir, predict(m_pcoa,data) siendo data la información para las variables utilizadas. En cualquier caso, estaría bien un ejemplo reproducible

Sí, es lo que pongo en predict(), pero me dice que predict no sirve para un objeto de tipo pcoa. Intento subir un ejemplo en un rato.

Editado! Gracias.
